# Raspberry Pi でデスクトップ環境を変更したとき、スプラッシュスクリーンを表示されないようにするには

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, x11

現在最新版のRaspbianをインストールすると「PIXEL」というデスクトップ環境が起動します。これを Xfce4 に変更しようと思いました。

```
# update-alternatives --config x-window-manager
```

で、`/usr/bin/xfwm4`を選択、

```
# update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

で、`/usr/bin/startxfce4`を選択しました。

これで、Xfce4を起動することはできたのですが、起動中にPIXELのスプラッシュスクリーンが表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Welcome to PIXEL と表示されますが、実際に起動するのは Xfce4 という状況になりました。

このスプラッシュスクリーンを表示されないようにするには、どうしたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

自己解決しました。

Raspbianの起動時の設定ファイル`/boot/cmdline.txt`に`splash`という記述があって、これを削除することで、スプラッシュスクリーンを非表示にすることができました。

対策方法は、
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/#comment-1263848
↑ で見つけました。

その他、「cmdline.txt splash」等で検索すると、関連情報が見つかりました。